# real eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let matrix $A$ be
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
>  -5& 1& 0& 0\\
>   a &2& 1 &0\\
>   0& 1 &1 &1\\
>   0 &0&1& 0
> \end{bmatrix}$$ 
>   where $a$ is a constant between 1 and 3.
>
> Show that the dominant eigenvalue is real.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: calculating explicitly is not possible Gershgorin circle theorem gives info for the absolute value??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A$ is a real [tridiagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix). One property of real tridiagonal matrices is this: if the *signs* of the entries in the upper and lower diagonals are symmetric (i.e. the $(i,\,i+1)$-th and $(i+1,\,i)$-th entries have the same sign for every $i$), then the matrix is similar to a real symmetric matrix and hence ***all*** of its eigenvalues are real. Now this is your case here.

Comment: How to show that @user1551 ?

Comment: See [these slides](http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/ICM/LecturesAndSeminars/08OctMaterials/1/Slide3.pdf), for instance.